# Can not Enable Public Link in AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, testflight-public-link

Following the steps WWDC video show, I am Admin and App Manager, but can not get the url to distribute app with link. Any idea how to do it?

```
To enable your link, you’ll need to be an Admin or App Manager. Go to any external tester group and click Enable Public Link
```

If TestFlight Public Link is not available do you know it it will be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After test binary was approved, I could create the Public Link. So first you need to assign a binary to your group, and apple need to approve that test binary before public link appear.

Comment: Please explain your answer. I've the same problem.

Comment: Is there any indication about the approving process?